Funding Unfunded Account using Smart Contract
I am searching a way to fund a account using smart conttact, that work fine if the receiver is already done some transactions. This is failing if there is no transactions done on the account.
How can I fix this issue?
pub fn send_sol(ctx: Context<SendSol>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let pda_account = &ctx.accounts.pda_account;
        let owner = &ctx.accounts.owner;
        let receiver = &ctx.accounts.receiver;

        // Validate that the sender is the owner of the PDA
        require_keys_eq!(pda_account.owner, *owner.key, PDAError::Unauthorized);

        msg!("Owner Matched");
        msg!("PDA Account : {}", pda_account.key());

        **pda_account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= amount;
        **receiver.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += amount;

        msg!(
            "Transferred {} lamports from PDA to {}",
            amount,
            ctx.accounts.receiver.key()
        );

        Ok(())
    }

Thanks

Can you please share the fail error and perhaps the failed transaction link so that people can assist better?
